# segmentation fault while erasing from a set in c++

Tags: c++, stl, computational-geometry

`eq` is the event queue where every element is of the form e = (F = (int, double), S = (int, double)).
When I process an event e = (F, S) in the event queue I either insert or delete or insert e.S from the `set< pair<int, double> > el`. While deleting `e.S` you can suppose that `e.S` is already in `el`.

But, when i am trying to delete `e.S` from `el` by `el.erase(e.S)` it gives an error:

> segmentation fault 11

Please Help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>
#include <set>

#define MP make_pair
#define PB push_back
#define F first
#define S second
#define OUT cout <<
#define IN cin >>
#define newline cout << "\n"
#define space cout << " "
#define fastIO ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);
#define PI 3.14159265
#define EPSILON 1e-9
#define OBJ pair<int, double>
#define EVENT pair< OBJ, OBJ >

using namespace std;

struct point {
    int x, y;
};

double angle(double x, double y) {
    double t = atan2 (y, x) * 180.0 / PI;
    return t >= 0 ? t : 360 - fabs(t);
}

vector< struct point > vp;

struct COMP {
    bool operator()(const EVENT &p, const EVENT &q) {
        if(fabs(p.F.S - q.F.S) > EPSILON) {
            return p.F.S < q.F.S;
        }
        else if(p.F.F != q.F.F) return p.F.F == 0;
        else return p.S.S < q.S.S;
    }
} comp_eq;

vector< EVENT > eq;

class comp_el {
public:
    bool operator()(const OBJ &p, const OBJ &q) {
        if(fabs(p.S - q.S) > EPSILON) {
            return p.S < q.S;
        }
        else {
            double a_p = angle(vp[p.F].y, vp[p.F].x), a_q = angle(vp[q.F].y, vp[q.F].x);
            if(fabs(a_p - a_q) > EPSILON) return a_p < a_q;
            else return false;
        }
    }
};

set< OBJ, comp_el > el;

int main() {
    int n, r;
    double theta, phi, d, beg, end;
    vector<struct point> vp;
    struct point p;
    while(1) {
        IN n;
        if(n == 0) break;
        eq.clear();
        vp.clear();
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            IN p.x;
            IN p.y;
            IN r;
            vp.PB(p);
            d = sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y);
            theta = angle(p.y, p.x);
            phi = asin(r/d);
            beg = theta - phi;
            beg = beg < 0 ? 360 - fabs(beg) : beg;
            eq.PB(MP(MP(0, beg), MP(j, d)));
            if(fabs(beg - 0) < EPSILON) {
                eq.PB(MP(MP(0, 360), MP(j, d)));
                eq.PB(MP(MP(1, 360), MP(j, d)));
            }
            end = beg + 2 * phi;
            if(fabs(end - 360) > EPSILON) {
                if(end > 360) {
                    eq.PB(MP(MP(1, 360), MP(j, d)));
                    eq.PB(MP(MP(0, 0), MP(j, d)));
                    eq.PB(MP(MP(1, end - 360), MP(j, d)));
                }
                else eq.PB(MP(MP(1, end), MP(j, d)));
            }
            else {
                eq.PB(MP(MP(1, 360), MP(j, d)));
                eq.PB(MP(MP(0, 0), MP(j, d)));
                eq.PB(MP(MP(1, 0), MP(j, d)));
            }
        }
        sort(eq.begin(), eq.end(), comp_eq);


        //I NEED HELP IN THE PART BELOW.


        for(int j = 0; j < eq.size(); j++) {
            EVENT e = eq[j];
            OUT e.F.F;
            space;
            OUT e.F.S;
            space;
            OUT e.S.F;
            space;
            OUT e.S.S;
            space;
            newline;
        }
        double maxD = -INT_MAX;
        for(int j = 0; j < eq.size(); j++) {
            EVENT e = eq[j];
            if(e.F.F == 0) {
                el.insert(e.S);
            }
            else {
                el.erase(e.S);
            }
            set< OBJ >::iterator first = el.begin();
            // for(; first != el.end(); first++){
            //  OUT (*first).F; space; OUT (*first).S;
            // }
            // newline;
            if(first != el.end()) {
                OUT (*first).F;
                space;
                OUT (*first).S;
                newline;
                if((*first).S > maxD) maxD = (*first).S;
            }
        }
        OUT maxD;
        newline;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you define make_pair to MP, push_back to PB and more? This is really bad style in my opinion. It doesn't really help to write the code faster, but makes it 100 times more difficult to read the code. A push_back(make_pair(Foo)) combination should be reduced to emplace_back(Foo).

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: `beg = theta - phi` doesn't make much sense: `theta` is in degrees but `phi` is in radians.

Answer (score 0):

`comp_el` attempts to look up elements in the global variable `vp` - but that vector is always empty. `main()` instead populates a local variable, which happens to also be named `vp`, but is otherwise distinct from and unrelated to the global `vp`. Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing vector elements with an index out of bounds.

---

Note also that comparators based on "close enough" almost-equality (as in, `fabs(p.F.S - q.F.S) > EPSILON`) don't generally satisfy the requirements of a strict weak ordering. The equivalence relation such a comparator induces is not transitive: it is possible to find three elements `A`, `B` and `C` such that `A` is close enough to `B` and `B` is close enough to `C`, but `A` is not close enough to `C`.